# How to display current weekday, the days before it and auto-change according to local time in Angular Material tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to make an angular material tab to display a current weekday and the 7 days before it and make it able to change according to the local machine for example, if today is Thursday I want a text to display Thursday for first tab, the 2 tabs to show Wednesday and so on.

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I try this `https://thisinterestsme.com/javascript-get-day-of-week/` but got nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assembled a quick demo for you of how it could be achieved [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fer9qx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.ts).

```js
    const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    const today = new Date();
    this.layout = [...Array(8).keys()].map(i => days[(i + today.getDay()) % days.length]);
    this.layout[this.layout.length - 1] = "Last " + this.layout[this.layout.length - 1];
```

Here's the code that builds an array of days starting with today, and ending with `Last {today}`.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot!
BTW how can I made it show the days one by one because I need to put other stuff in the tabs

Comment: What do you mean one by one? Btw, you can ask another question and describe what you're trying to accomplish in detail ;)

Comment: I want to put in other documents inside the tabs. but from your code, the tabs are already filled with `Hello from {{item}}` so I want to change what inside the tab one by one.